# What is the path that I need to put in for a cron job

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I have a script, `site_backup.sh`, that works fine from the command line.

I want to run a cron job for it but I need help. The file is stored at:

```
/home/username/public_html/backups
```

I have tried this but it doesn't do anything:

```
0   0   *   *   *   /bin/sh /home/username/public_html/backups/site_backup.sh
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the cron job is in /etc/cron.d/ you need to add the user that the script should be run as: `0 0 * * * root /home/username/public_html/backups/site_backup.sh`

Comment: _Doesn't do anything_ meaning? Note that, you are running the `cron` job at `00:00` i.e. at the start of each day.

Comment: I set it to run every 5 minutes as well but the backup doesn't happen

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to put /bin/sh in front of the command.
Make sure the file site_backup.sh is executable and it will work.

If your script has any graphical output, place `export DISPLAY=:0 &&` in front of your command, so it will look like

`0   0   *   *   *  export DISPLAY=:0 && /home/username/public_html/backups/site_backup.sh`

Comment: Yes the file is executable as it works if I run it manually.

Comment: I have tried it without the /bin/sh as well but the backup script still doesn't run

Comment: Are you aware, that your script is set to run only at the beginning of day, i.e. at 00:00 each day?

Comment: Yes, sorry I have also set it to run every 5 minutes to see if the backup starts but it doesn't

Comment: And have you replaced the string "username" with your actuall username?

Comment: LOL, yes. I am a novice but yes I have replaced that